# Your bucket has not been set up properly for Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Please can someone help me with this error from `firebaseStorage`?

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 400,    "message": "Your bucket has not been set up properly for Firebase Storage. Please visit 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/task-management-app-99c32/storage/files' to automatically repair this issue and then retry. If the issue lasts longer than five minutes, you may have insufficient permissions to repair the project. You can check your permissions by visiting 'https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=task-management-app-99c32'."  }}

Answer (score 7):

You can change your Firebase Storage rules to be as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Storage rules of firebase

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true; // true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change Realtime database rules

```
 {
  "rules" : {
    ".read" : true,
      ".write" : true
  }
}
```